# A Place Where Fanatics Rule

Tags: riddle, visual, knowledge, story, acrostic

> I woke up. It was really hot, and the last thing I remembered was seeing the faces of my family in a white surrounding. Well, actually there was something before that. I remember seeing a weird symbol.

$\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\quad$ [image: SYMBOL]

> It was strange; it must have been a dream. I looked ahead and a man then greeted me. He had pointy ears and a pointy beard, but he looked quite handsome nonetheless.
>
> "I have been expecting you," he said holding a black cat. "Follow me." I didn't want to though. I was tired, but I followed him anyway. He walked very proudly, I noticed.
>
> He lead me to an acrobatics centre, where people dressed up in suits with long tails were doing all these tricks! "Welcome to the Lewderthorn Acrobatics Centre!" the man said. *Lewderthorn?* I thought. *As in, "Lewder"? An odd name for an acrobatics centre...* I looked at all the people and stared. They were:
>
> - Crossing each other whilst doing handstands;
> - Up in the air and falling down in ribbons;
> - Running and jogging in a large figure eight;
> - Star-jumping in circles and doing cartwheels; and
> - Executing somersaults into a pit of foam hexahedrons.
>
> They were so brilliant, I became kinda jealous... until a particular thought came to mind. "This is the perfect place for you," said the man, making the OK symbol with his hand (as somebody did a handstand with his legs in the air).

$\qquad$ $\qquad$ [image] [image]

> Three black dogs then ran up to me and started licking me. 
>  I turned my head to the man and realised who he was. 
>  I didn't want to be here.
>
> But it was too late. "I'm gonna head off and eat, now," said the man. "You stay here, hahahahah." And he was gone.
>
> It was at that moment, that the dogs stopped licking and started growling and barking and raging. 
>  And all the gymnasts began laughing as they crowded around me. 
>  And the only thing I could hear was my screams.

## ***Who was the man?*** 
 ***Why was I here? (Bonus)***

---

*Inspired by @[PerpetualJ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51105/perpetualj)'s story riddles. Please check them out if you have not already!*

Answer (score 4):

Partial:
The acrostic is clearly visible:

> CURSE, I am not able to find any other yet.

Also you saw 3 black dogs which can be explained as:

> A black dog is a spectral or demonic entity found primarily in the folklore of the British Isles. The black dog is essentially a nocturnal apparition, some of them shapeshifters, and are often said to be associated with the Devil or described as a ghost or hellhound. Its appearance was regarded as a portent of death.

Which can be a signify:

> In Greek mythology the **hellhound Cerberus** belonged to Hades. **Cerberus** was said to be a massive, three-headed black dog that guarded the entrance to the underworld.

Also,

> the symbol you saw seems to have some greek origin. somewhat similar to the symbol of Hades or Epimetheus.

The Gym,

> The name: **Lewderthorn**:
> **Lewder** - comparative form of lewd
>  **Lewd** - crude and offensive in a sexual way.
>  **Thorn**- a source of discomfort, annoyance, or difficulty; an irritation or obstacle 
>  This feels like some torturous place. maybe you are in **Hell** or the **Underworld**

Also to the name confirms this by:

> **Lewderthorn** is and Anagram or **Netherworld** - (meaning) Underworld or Hell

---

This might help someone else

> Title - **Fanatics** - creates **Satanic** as Anagram if only F(the capital letter or first letter) is ignored
> Removing all caps gives
> *lace **here Satanic** ule* - I am not sure if it makes sense

Comment: You are definitely on the right track. Your progress is great, thus far, and you are looking in the right areas. Also, (ROT13) Gurer vf zber gb "Yrjqregubea". Gel svthevat vg bhg (lbh tbg irel pybfr jvgu "haqrejbeyq") :D

Comment: @user477343 yay... That makes my day.. I thought this would go completely of track..

Comment: No, no, it isn't. Just a little further and you might even get the answer. In fact, the answer to who the man was is actually *in* your answer... but is not your actual answer (yet) :P

Comment: @user477343 edited my answer at the bottom.. hope thats it or may help others

Comment: Yeah, it is. You can apply the same technique to a certain part of the title and you might uncover something, heheh... There is also more to the last part for the bonus, but it includes other things as well :P

Comment: Regarding the last part, (ROT13) "snangvpf" vf bar bs gur jbeqf gb hfr...

Comment: (ROT13) snangvpf gb "fngna svp" ... and building off the work done on this, (ROT13) gur zna vf fngna, which fits the description. Not posting as an answer, because naaem did all the work here.

Comment: @user477343  what do you think of the comment by Stidgeon

Comment: @NaeemShaikh it is correct, but the approach is wrong :P

Comment: @Stidgeon see the comment above :)